# Get subfolders from pysftp Connection

Tags: python, pysftp

I have an admin account where customers upload files in a subdirectory.

```
import pysftp as sftp
import os

cnopts = sftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None  

s = sftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts)
folderlist = s.listdir()
```

This gives me back the following array:

```
['Customer_1', 'Customer_2', 'Customer_3', 'Customer_4']
```

`folderlist[0].listdir()` does not work here. How can I access the subdirectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
s.listdir(remotepath=folderlist[0])
```

folderlist[0] is a string.